# MongoDb Query - Filtering results based on grouped sum

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am new to mongodb and trying do some prototyping to see if it is best fit. In short I am trying to create an inventory tracking database. Which tracks the movement In and Out of various products by quantities. In table format it would look like this:

| product_id | product_name | quantity | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sugar | 100 |  |
| 1 | sugar | -100 |  |
| 2 | flour | 50 | Jun stock |
| 2 | flour | -50 | Sold to John |
| 3 | water | 100 | Arrived in June |
| 4 | water | 100 | Arrive in July |

So in short when product:

- ADDED to the inventory it is given a POSITIVE quantity.
- REMOVED from inventory is given a NEGATIVE quantity.

**MY QUESTION**

What is the best way to run a query to work out the stock on site? Meaning summing the product_ids and only displaying matching results where the sum of the quantity is greater than 0?

I've come across group$ can you feed these results into another query eg find to get the matching records?

Also by best way I mean considering there a many records what would scale for a larger record set say 100K-200K of records?

The expected results would be:

| product_id | product_name | quantity | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | water | 100 | Arrived in June |
| 4 | water | 100 | Arrive in July |

ie flour and sugar sum to 0 so they are not displayed. But water there is still a sum quantity above 0 onsite so they will be displayed.

I've setup a playgroud of the data set:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/zzPX8Da09SB

Also data object below. Thanks you very much for any tips or best approach.

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Sugar",
    "quantity": 100
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Sugar",
    "quantity": -100
  },
  {
    "product_id": 3,
    "product_name": "Flour",
    "quantity": 50
  },
  {
    "product_id": 3,
    "product_name": "Flour",
    "quantity": -50
  },
  {
    "product_id": 4,
    "product_name": "Water",
    "quantity": 100
  },
  {
    "product_id": 5,
    "product_name": "Water",
    "quantity": 100
  }
]
```

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        product_id: "$product_id",
        product_name: "$product_name"
      },
      quantity: {
        $sum: "$quantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      quantity: {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  }
]). It works now. Please Check .https://mongoplayground.net/p/AbT4fBpbG5k

Comment: Thank you so much exactly how I needed it! Works! Thought it would much more complicated than this

Comment: Welcome @Ka Tech